# How can capture an image along with logo and text in 3D canvas?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, html5-canvas, webgl

[image]
 I am new in Three js .I am showing  3d model in the canvas along with logo and text message .When I capture canvas by `renderer.domElement.toDataURL('image/jpeg')` .It will give me only model image and it excluded logo and text from capture image.

Please see the attached image .
How can i  capture 3d model along with logo and text?

```
<canvas height="1024" id="stageCanvas" width="1024" style="cursor: pointer"></canvas>
<div ng-class="{'preview-gif-option1': gifImageType.type == 'Option 1'}" ng-if="gifImageType.type == 'Option 1'">
  <img ng-src="{{watermarkImage}}" ng-show="watermarkImage != null" alt="" style="height:100px;width:100px" />
  <pre>{{addressInfo.value}}</pre>
</div>
```

```
  $scope.captureJpg = function() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
  rotateAngle = 0;
  rotateObject(rotateAngle);
  animate();
  $scope.captureClicked = false;
  console.log(renderer.domElement.toDataURL('image/jpeg')); 
};
```

Comment: Do your logo, image and text have anything to do with webgl, canvas and threejs?

Comment: I want to add logo and text in three js canvas .but didn't  successful so I put  logo and text in div .I can capture images of 3d model but I want to to capture all .that means I want to put watermark after capturing canvas

Answer (score 2):

3 options

1. Put the logo in a texture, use the texture in a material, apply the material to a plane, put the plane in your scene

   ```
   const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
   const tex = loader.load('path/to/logo');
   const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: tex});
   const geo = new THREE.PlaneBufferMaterial(width, height);
   const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material);
   scene.add(mesh);
   mesh.position.set(x, y, z); // choose an appropriate position
   ```
2. Create a 2D canvas, draw the three.js canvas into the 2D canvas, draw the logo image into the 2D canvas, call toDataURL on the 2D canvas

   ```
   const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
   ctx.canvas.width = widthYouWant;
   ctx.canvas.height = heightYouWant;
   ctx.drawImage(renderer.domElement, 0, 0);
   ctx.drawImage(logoImgYouAlreadyLoaded, 300, 150); // set the appropriate position
   const dataURL = ctx.canvas.toDataURL();
   ```
3. Use [a library](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) for capturing HTML.

   note you will need to pass in `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` when creating the `THREE.WebGLRenderer`